# Accessing Data in Array - Non-Object Error PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I'm populating an array like this:

```
 $POarray = array();
 foreach($orders as $order)
    {
        $total = OrderItems::where('OrderID', $order->OrderID)->sum('TotalPrice') * (1 + $LRmarkup);
        $arraydata = array(
            'Name' => $order->OrderNumber, 
            'Total' => $total);

        $POarray[] = $arraydata;    

    }
```

This results in the contents of the $POarray variable being:

```
[
 {
  "Name": "DS-BS-18102654",
  "Total": 241.4655
 },
 {
  "Name": "test test",
  "Total": "600.00"
 }
]
```

I am attempting to access this data like this:

```
 $purchase1name = $POarray[0]->Name;
 $purchase1total = $POarray[0]->Total;
```

And I am getting this error:

```
 "Trying to get property of non-object"
```

Shouldn't this work?

Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: I don't see any objects added to $POarray so did you want $POarray[0]['Name'] for example? Have a look at the output of `var_dump($POarray)` and I think you'll find it's a 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

$POarray is not an object.

Try:

```
$purchase1name = $POarray[0]['Name'];
$purchase1total = $POarray[0]['Total'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this way after decoding it using `json_decode()`,

```
<?php

$key='[
 {
  "Name": "DS-BS-18102654",
  "Total": 241.4655
 },
 {
  "Name": "test test",
  "Total": "600.00"
 }
]';

$POarray = json_decode($key);

echo $POarray[0]->Name;
echo $POarray[0]->Total;

?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/JvCam

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this.

```
array_get($POarray[0], 'Name');
array_get($POarray[0], 'Total');
```

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers